# Placing a comma when not a dialog

Tags: parenthetical-commas

Which way is correct for American usage?

He adopted the anglicized version "Edward C. Cordel."
or
He adopted the anglicized version "Edward C. Cordel".

He refused to "pick up a crown out of the gutter."
or
He refused to "pick up a crown out of the gutter".

Comment: Erm...do you mean period (full stop)? This is dupy to a post from only last week...I'll try to find it.

Comment: Have you ever seen an American edited publication place the period outside of the quotation mark?

Comment: @Kay be sure to mark your preferred answer as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it!

Answer (score 1):

Kay! The period goes inside of the quotation marks!

1) He adopted the anglicized version "Edward C. Cordel."

2) He refused to "pick up a crown out of the gutter."

This rule is explained by Purdue Owl if you need any more help :)

> Put commas and periods within quotation marks, except when a parenthetical reference follows. - Purdue Owl, https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/577/03/

Comment: It's a matter of distinction between AmE and BrE as also among various style guides/ style gurus. There's no single canonical rule.

Comment: Do not use "answer" to post comments. Read the FAQ. This is not supported by any references.

Comment: I wasn't critiquing or requesting clarification. I was answering her question! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Pink. The comment from Oliver Mason was generated by an AI flagging VLQ  posts. If  a link and citation are not seen, the AI will rear its ugly head, and complain about the brevity of the answer. When you have reached 1000 rep (I think) you wil be able to access those privileges.